# Ktor CIO wss socket closes immediately

Tags: websocket, kotlin, ktor

When using ktor CIO ws it works as expected, but when using wss it gets closed immediately. Any help is greatly appreciated. been stuck for a day now.

This is the stack trace I'm getting for wss

```
kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.ClosedReceiveChannelException: Channel was closed
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.Closed.getReceiveException(AbstractChannel.kt:1067)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.AbstractChannel$ReceiveElement.resumeReceiveClosed(AbstractChannel.kt:907)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.AbstractSendChannel.helpClose(AbstractChannel.kt:317)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.AbstractSendChannel.close(AbstractChannel.kt:254)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.ChannelCoroutine.close(ChannelCoroutine.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.SendChannel$DefaultImpls.close$default(Channel.kt:84)
    at io.ktor.network.tls.TLSClientHandshake$input$1.doResume(TLSClientHandshake.kt:96)
    at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resumeWithException(CoroutineImpl.kt:48)
    at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resumeWithException(CoroutineImpl.kt:47)
    at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:41)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:149)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.io.internal.MutableDelegateContinuation.run(MutableDelegateContinuation.kt:14)
    at io.ktor.network.util.IOCoroutineDispatcher$IODispatchedTask.run(IOCoroutineDispatcher.kt)
    at io.ktor.network.util.IOCoroutineDispatcher$IOThread$run$1.doResume(IOCoroutineDispatcher.kt:73)
    at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:149)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedContinuation.run(Dispatched.kt:13)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.EventLoopBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.kt:140)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:70)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:46)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at io.ktor.network.util.IOCoroutineDispatcher$IOThread.run(IOCoroutineDispatcher.kt:68)
```

here's the code:

```
httpClient.ws(host = "echo.websocket.org") {
  send(Frame.Text("Hello World"))

  for (message in incoming.map { it as? Frame.Text }.filterNotNull()) {
    println(message.readText())
  }
}

httpClient.wss(host = "echo.websocket.org") {
  send(Frame.Text("Hello World"))

  for (message in incoming.map { it as? Frame.Text }.filterNotNull()) {
    println(message.readText())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I there was an issue with secure WebSockets and it is fixed in ktor `1.3.2`.

I also want to mention that `echo.websocket.org` doesn't close connection, so the for loop will be suspended forever(expecting the next pong message).

To avoid that you can rewrite this

```kotlin
for (message in incoming.map { it as? Frame.Text }.filterNotNull()) {
    println(message.readText())
}
```

as

```kotlin
val pong = incoming.receive() as Frame.Text
println(pong.readText())
```

It also should be ok to call `close()` explicitly after sending the first message, but it's unsupported for now. I filed the separate issue for that:  https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1946